# Xamarin XamlParseException

Tags: android, exception, xamarin

I get this Exception when I try to make a release for Android. I have no problems building a release for iPhone.

```
Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 10:5. Type convertor:NotConverter not found in xmlns clr-namespace:Comca.Helpers.Convertors;assembly=Comca.Helpers.Convertors
```

I tried this:

```
namespace:Comca;assembly=Comca.Helpers.Convertors
```

and this:

```
namespace:Comca.Helpers.Convertors;assembly=Comca
```

Keep getting the error here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:convertor="clr-namespace:Comca.Helpers.Convertors;assembly=Comca.Helpers.Convertors"
    x:Class="Comca.App">
```

Here is the class:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Comca.Helpers.Convertors
{
public class NotConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !(bool)value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !(bool)value;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm completely lost.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: is the Converter located in your shared project?  Is it a PCL or a Shared Library?  What is it (the project) named?

Comment: Jason, thanks. Located in the shared project, it is a PCL. Today it works, I don't get any errors. I haven't changed anything.